# lb web-client export always using /tmp directory

Tags: logicblox

In my `lb-web-server.config` file I have set the following:

```
[handler:delimited-file]
classname = com.logicblox.bloxweb.delim.DelimitedFileHandler
tmpdir = /my/temp/dir
```

When I run an export with `lb web-client export --no-compress --output /some/dir/myfile.csv http://service-uri` a temporary file is created in `/my/temp/dir`, but several files are also written to `/tmp`:

```
-rw-r--r--.  1 root       root         109M Oct  9 12:13 tmp21498_2316_XXYMElJ4
-rw-r--r--.  1 root       root         106M Oct  9 12:13 tmp21498_2317_XXTHg8fE
-rw-r--r--.  1 root       root         114M Oct  9 12:15 tmp21498_2318_XXQhuWvW
-rw-r--r--.  1 root       root         106M Oct  9 12:15 tmp21498_2319_XX7KbYmo
```

When the combined size of these temp files exceeds the available space on `/tmp`, the export fails.

Am I missing an additional setting in `lb-web-server.config` which would cause these files to be written to the correct location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can avoid storing these temp files under `/tmp` by setting the `LB_TEMPDIR` environment variable to another directory.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear the runtime is using "generic" temporary files, whose location is controlled by the environment variable `LB_TEMPDIR` (defaulting to /tmp). I'm not aware of any config file setting to control it, unfortunately.

I will file a bug.